"Fatal error: Duplicate keys of type 'DisplayList' were found in a Dictionary", when plotting lots of rectangles in R
I was just doing some routine plotting in R that involved a lot of rectangles. I plotted a blank canvas and then started tailing them with rect() function in a for loop (reproducible code below).
However, once per while, when in an interactive mode, the R session crashes with following error
Fatal error: Duplicate keys of type 'DisplayList' were found in a Dictionary.
This usually means either that the type violates Hashable's requirements, or
that members of such a dictionary were mutated after insertion.
Trace/BPT trap: 5

It is a glitch, it does not happen every rime, but in one in few thousand of rectangles plotted. Does not happen when plotted within an Rscript, only in an interactive session.
With a bit got googling it seems this is an error message of Swift, which makes me think it's an Mac OS specific problem of R using a Swift library. I got to say, I am not even sure where to start to get it fixed and if it's a Swift or R problem.
This R code crashes every other run
pal <- c("coral", "dodgerblue", "darkseagreen2")
table_with_data <- data.frame(left = 0:9, right = 1:10, bot = rep(0:999, each = 10), top = rep(1:1000, each = 10), col = sample(pal, replace = T, 10000))
plot(NULL, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0,1000))
for (i in 1:nrow(table_with_data)){
    rect(table_with_data$left[i], table_with_data$bot[i], table_with_data$right[i], table_with_data$top[i], col = table_with_data$col[i], border = NA)
}

This is on a MacBook pro with M1 chip running OS Sonoma 14.5 and R version 4.2.3.

Unrelated but it’s crash not crush.

I’ve been having the same problem for months, also on M1. I’m not sure though why R would use a Swift library on MacOS. The only MacOS-specific thing about plots I can see is that windows are generated using XQuartz. Could that be an XQuartz problem?

@kamil-s-jaron Do you happen to run R inside a conda environment? I noticed that I only observe this bug when my R session is launch from inside a conda env.
A simple oneliner that triggers the issue on my side is:
library(ggplot2); for (i in seq(1,1000)) {p <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + geom_point() + theme_bw(); print(p)}

I do have an active conda, but the R installation is not within it. It's system wide.

I made more tests and I confirm, it also happens outside conda environment. Looking at the crash message, I suspect an issue in QuartzCore (hence in Sonoma 14.5). I did not manage to reproduce inside RStudio when plots are made directly inside (device is set to "RStudioGD"). If I set the device to "quartz", the issue occurs again.

I can confirm that the bug is absent from MacOS Sonoma 14.4 and present in MacOS Sonoma 14.5, with all versions of R I tested... It seems related to Quartz. The workarounds I found so far while waiting for the next system upgrade are:

Use RStudio with the default device ("RStudioGD") that does not seem to trigger the issue or,
Subscribe to Apple Beta and install 14.6 beta 2. I wasn’t able to trigger the issue on this version so far.

Hope this helps. 14.5 was released on May so hopefully 14.6 stable should be released soon.
